# Deleting using Entity Framework and calling controller method in ajax

Tags: ajax, controller, entity-framework-5

I have been trying to create a delete button in mvc using json to call the delete method in my controller but so far its not working.

I did trap the error alert in the script and the success section is not registering a thing, I need help well here is my view, that picks data from SQL Server using Entity Framework 5.1.

I am working with a table called `Departments` and it has two columns, `DepartmentId` and `DepartmentName`.

```
<div class="container" style="width:40%; margin-top:2%;">
    <hr />
    <table class="table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <th>Deprtment Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        @if(ViewBag.RowDepartmentList != null)
        {
            foreach(var item in ViewBag.RowDepartmentList)
            {
                 <tr id="row_@item.DepartmentId"> 
                     <td>@item.DepartmentId</td>
                     <td>@item.DepartmentName</td>
                     <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ConfirmDelete(@item.DepartmentId)">
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                 </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenDepartmentId" />   
</div>
```

I added a hidden attribute to capture the `DepartmentId`, the form too has a delete button that first calls a delete dialog modal.

My `DELETE` dialog modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:350px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class=" modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
            </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Delete record</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="DelDepartment()">Delete</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what my controller looks like:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Employee
    public ActionResult DepartmentIndex()
    {
        MVCTutorialEntities2 db = new MVCTutorialEntities2();

        List<EmployeeViewModel> emlist = db.Departments.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == 0).Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel {DepartmentId=x.Departmentid, DepartmentName = x.DepartmentName }).ToList();

        ViewBag.RowDepartmentList = emlist;

        return View();
    }

    // the delete function
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DelDepartment(int depId)
    {
        MVCTutorialEntities2 db = new MVCTutorialEntities2();
        bool result = false;
        Department dep = db.Departments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Departmentid == depId);

        if (dep != null)
        {
            db.Departments.Remove(dep);      // I don't know why this is not deleting .... the table is not cascaded
            db.SaveChanges();

            result = true;
        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

// now my script is all here that calls the     
<script>
var ConfirmDelete = function (DepartmentId) {
     $("#HiddenDepartmentId").val(DepartmentId);
     $("#mymodal").modal("show");
}

var DelDepartment = function ()
{
    var depId = $("#HiddenDepartmentId").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Employee/DelDepartment',
        data: { DepartmentId: depId },

         success: function (result) {$("#mymodal").modal("hide"); },
         error: function (result) { alert(result); $("#mymodal").modal("hide"); }  // only the error section resturns a message of [object] of [object]
    });
}
</script>
```

Trying so hard to learn this language ... and if so, is there any way I can just use razor and call the delete function from the

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("", "",FormMethod.POST)) ?
```

function?

Answer (score 0):

data: { DepartmentId: depId } needs to be

data: { depId: depId } because the left JS parameter name has to match up with the parameter name on the controller side.

Or you may need to do:  data: JSON.stringify({ depId: depId })

If that doesn't work, you can do url: 'Employee/DelDepartment?depId=' + deptId and just get rid of the data property altogether.